# AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute 'var', checkbox tkinter in python

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox

I cannot send checkbox value with submit like other fields.

I have problem with sending checkbox value. I cannot do get as with other fields. I tried with var, but also doesn't work. I need to send value with submit so if license is checked, I should skip new entering of license,othereise, I should add it.

class SimpleDialog(Frame):

```
is_license_checked:  int = 0

entry_is_license_checked: tkinter.Checkbutton
```

def init_ui(self, dialog_name: str) -> None:

```
frame_is_license_checked = Frame(self)
frame_is_license_checked.pack(fill=X)

label_is_license_checked = Label(frame_is_license_checked, text="<License already activated", width=30)
label_is_license_checked.pack(side=RIGHT, pady=10)

# self.entry_is_license_checked = tkinter.Checkbutton(frame_is_license_checked, offvalue="", textvariable=StringVar(value=self.is_license_checked))
# self.entry_is_license_checked = tkinter.Checkbutton(frame_is_license_checked, offvalue="", variable=self.is_license_checked)

self.entry_is_license_checked = tkinter.Checkbutton(frame_is_license_checked, offvalue=0, onvalue=1, variable=IntVar(value=self.is_license_checked))
self.entry_is_license_checked.pack(fill=X, expand=True, side=RIGHT)
```

...

```
def submit(self) -> None:
    self.user_name = self.entry_username.get()
    self.password = self.entry_password.get()
    self.test_selection = self.entry_test_selection.get()
    self.gxp_license_key = self.entry_pxp_license_key.get()
    self.is_license_checked.var = self.entry_is_license_checked - Here I have error, Also I cannot do get()

    self.quit()
```

Comment: Show us the whole class definition.

Comment: Showing the whole class definition would have made it easier but I was still able to replicate his issue with a barebones implementation. My solution to the issue is posted below.

Comment: It is better to fix the formatting of your posted code and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce your problem by creating a new Tkinter app that includes a Checkbutton and a Button. I was able to solve your issue by fixing the `is_license_checked` variable to be of type `IntVar` and can access it by using it's `get` method. An example of this is posted below.

```
# replace the current is_licence_checked variable declaration with the following
is_licence_checked: IntVar = None

# replace the current self.entry_is_license_checked declaration with the following
self.is_license_checked = IntVar()
self.entry_is_license_checked = tkinter.Checkbutton(frame_is_license_checked, variable=self.is_license_checked)
```

Just make sure to assign the value of `self.is_license_checked` to `IntVar()` right before creating the button. Doing it too early will result in a RuntimeError. After these changes have been implemented, you no longer need to set the value of `self.is_license_checked` inside of the `submit` method. You can instead just access the value anytime by calling `self.is_license_checked.get()`.

If you noticed, I also removed the `offvalue=0` and `onvalue=1` options from inside the `Checkbutton` declaration. This is because they are the default values and do not need to be included.

If for some reason you are unable to or prefer not to change the `is_license_checked` type to `IntVar`, you could instead create a new variable for this and update `is_license_checked` from within your `submit` method. An example of this would look like the following.

```
# replace the current self.entry_is_license_checked declaration
self.entry_is_license_checked_value = IntVar()
self.entry_is_license_checked = tkinter.Checkbutton(frame_is_license_checked, variable=self.entry_is_license_checked_value)


def submit(self) -> None:
    ...
    # update self.is_license_checked to the value of the Checkbutton variable
    self.is_license_checked = self.entry_is_license_checked_value.get()
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`IntVar()` helped me, but I had to solve it on this way.

```
self.is_license_checked = IntVar()
self.entry_is_license_checked = ttk.Checkbutton(frame_is_license_checked, text="SMP already activated",variable = self.is_license_checked)
                                                       

def submit(self) -> None:
self.is_license_checked = self.entry_is_license_checked.instate(['selected'])
```

On this way I got true or false value, so that I can check it later.

When I tried to call `self.is_license_checked.get()`, I didn't get proper value, in debugging I saw response *PY_VAR2*.

When I try `self.is_license_checked = self.entry_is_license_checked_value.get()` I get error Expected type IntVar, got int instead.